# Why does TestNG ignoring my tests when I use constructor inside of the test class?

Tags: java, testng

During TestNG test run I've found out that if I want to init some fields using constructor - test class doesn't run any tests:

```
Default Suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

But when I remove the constructor - test class runs just fine.
What I've tried to solve the issue:

1. Removed DataProviders - did not help.
2. Removed the @Test annotation on class - did not help.

Debug didn't help since it doesn't even go into constructor.

Comment: Please put the code along with the question so that we would be able to help you better.

Comment: You don't init fields in a Test class using a constructor, you're supposed to use a `@BeforeTest` annotated method (usually named `setup`).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to set up an initial environment to perform certain tests, add the following:

```
@BeforeTest
public void init() {
    //perform intialisation
}
```

TestNG will always execute the `@BeforeTest` methods before executing `@Test` methods.